# Pythonic way to catch all exceptions from a module?

Tags: python, exception, rope

I am trying to do some refactoring using `rope` package. Depending on the code, it might throw exceptions and there are more than 10 rope exceptions.

I dont want to do

```
from rope.base.exceptions import *

try:
    # do something
except (AttributeNotFoundError, ModuleDecodeError,
        ..., ..., ..., RefactoringError) as e:
     # do something else
```

I just want to catch all rope exceptions, something like this

```
import rope

try:
    # do something
except rope.base.exceptions.*:
    # do something else
```

How to catch all exceptions from a specific module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just catch the base of all of the exceptions:

```
In [5]: import rope.base.exceptions as rbe
In [6]: try:
   ...:     raise rbe.AttributeNotFoundError
   ...: except rbe.RopeError, e:
   ...:     print "RopeError -", e
   ...:

RopeError!
```